# How do you show/hide comments on videos, in profile on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I notice that when you click "Feed", some people have comments listed, others don't.

How can I show/hide comments made on videos, from my profile, when people click feed?

Answer (score 1):

The option to choose what you want to show in the feeds are in Channel Settings -> Tab -> Feed --> Select what you want to be displayed in the feeds and then Save the settings.

I tried this on my YouTube channel but it didn't worked, but it's the only place to change the settings of YouTube channel, not sure why it isn't working.